# How can I have access in membership tables in mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use register and login form in MVC4 . I have used Entity Framework from DB to create the model and now I want to generate the membership tables, but I have tried many things and I still can't access them.

I have 2 connection strings :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Projekti-20160917211151;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Projekti-20160917211151.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

 <add name="UniversitetiEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Universiteti.csdl|res://*/Models.Universiteti.ssdl|res://*/Models.Universiteti.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ARBERS-PC\BERSANTA;initial catalog=Universiteti;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

In Account Model I changed the base in UniversitetiEntities :

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("UniversitetiEntities")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

I Also did this chang in InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute file:

```
 private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new UsersContext())

                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("UniversitetiEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it always throws this exception : The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, SimpleMembershipProvider user profile management only works with SQL Server database connection string, not an EF connection string.

First, try setting your DB connection string instead of EF-generated connection string as stated [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1939734.aspx?ASP+NET+Simple+Membership+database+could+not+be+initialized):

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
{
    public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

        try
        {
            using (var context = new UsersContext())
            {
                if (!context.Database.Exists())
                {
                    // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                }
            }

            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
        }
    }
}

// also set your DB connection string on current DB context
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

If the first solution won't work, try removing AttachDbFileName property from SQL Server connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Projekti-20160917211151;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

NB: If your DB connection has certain user ID & password to get access, include them in `DefaultConnection`.

Depending on your EF model generation (code first, database first or model first approach), you can set `autoCreateTables:` by true or false based from existence of `UserProfile` table.

Further information: [SimpleMembership Provider Reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates)

Comment: I changed it in"DefaultConnection" but I still get this error:  An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Projekti.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Please edit your question to include your error since `InvalidOperationException` could be triggered by certain conditions applied, specify exception detail & stack trace if any.